# No sound and no screen resolution

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, sound, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 a few days ago. It works fine but I have no sound (I tried reinstalling Alsa and Pulseaudio, installing NVIDIA drivers on my own, changing different blacklists and almost everything I found here).

I can't change the screen resolution either. I have no options to choose (only 1024x768). I could manage to make appear a new option but when I set it, the image has a size bigger than expected and when I reboot everything comes back to normal (which is 1024x768 and the new resolution dissapears from the list).

So here are my both problems.

Some details:
 - OS Ubuntu 18.04
 - NVIDIA GeForce 740 GK107
 - Motherboard ASUS H81M-K

Please, let me know if you need more information. And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could find the solution so I'll post it for anybody that could have the same problem.
It was the Secure Boot. I just had to disable it from the BIOS and that's all.
When the pc started everything was working fine. :)